# ssh remotely to raspbian os

Tags: linux, ssh

> Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

Currently I ssh into the operating system, from home, via `user_name@ip_address` + `password`.  I have set up a tunnel in my modem for this `ip_address` using `TCP`.

Am I wondering if I am able to ssh into the device from say someone else house?

Comment: By "a tunnel in my modem" you mean port forwarding? or what? If you did it right; and if there's no NAT (like carrier-grade NAT) on the route; and if ..., and if ... Have you just tried? What have you tried?

Comment: tab 'NAT' port forwarding, ip_address and port number

Comment: OK, this *may* work, if done right. So have you just tried to ssh from another location?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I haven't tried it.